# How to stop losing the context of a comment

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

Not sure how to phrase this.

Couple of times now I have replied to a comment and for whatever reason, may be something was pointed out that was wrong for example the original owner deletes the comment leaving my comment not making much sense.

Has this been brought up before, what is the reason to allow comments to be removed by their owners?

---

**OK, so it wasn't a feature request but...**

Wasn't meant to be a [feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) but after thinking about it some more decided to post it as such.

What do people think of this idea...

> If a comment is replied to they should no longer be able to edit or delete it.

Trying to think of ways preserving the context of a reply to a comment, at the moment people can just remove a comment and the context is lost. Some comments can become extremely difficult to follow.

---

> **Note:**
>
> Just occurred to me that this might be better posed on MSE.

Comment: This is an unavoidable consequence of comments being second-class citizens, by design.  Rule of thumb: if it needs to stay on the site, in context, it needs to be part of an on-topic post.

Comment: If someone says something wrong in a comment, and someone else points that out in another, not allowing the first to be removed would be completely counter-productive

Answer (score 4):

If someone commented incorrectly and that someone then deleted their comment then your comment has been a success. The original comment poster has recognised the error and removed incorrect content from the site.

Excellent!

After the comment you were commenting about it removed your comment will make less sense, yes. However, you're also correcting non-existent information. At this stage you have 3 options

1. Delete your comment - it has served its purpose, remove it
2. Leave your comment - you need to ensure that you provide context when commenting for this to be a viable option
3. Edit the post to include information about the exchange so that others don't make the same mistake. Don't include the exchange itself, but make the post clearer.